# iterate through mysql array and assign to variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

In PHP, how do I write the following in grown up code (pref Objected Oriented)?
I just can't get to grips with how PHP iterates through an array.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM newsletters WHERE ID = '1'");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM newsletters WHERE ID = '2'");
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM newsletters WHERE ID = '3'");
etc

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
$row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
etc

$title1 = $row{'name'};
$title2 = $row2{'name'};
$title3 = $row3{'name'};
etc
```

Ideally I would like the result, which is just names to display in a table, in $title[x].

Thanks.

Comment: First step to become a grown-up is to stop making a bunch of individual SQL queries for what should be done in one single query.

Comment: Second step is to not make negative comments. I knew it wasn't correct, that was my point, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. That was the point in asking the question. If people leave negative comments, beginners will think three times about asking questions and won't get the most out of the facility on offer. I know I will.

Comment: "put on hold as too broad by CBroe...If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question or leave a comment." Existing answers are great and helpful. They did the job. Responders obviously picked the right short answer and didn't find it too broad. Again my thanks to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get the name of all of the newsletters. If so you only need one query:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT name FROM newsletters');
```

If you want to fetch specific newsletters you can specify the IDs in the query:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT name FROM newsletters WHERE ID IN(1, 2, 3)');
```

You can use a while loop to iterate over the rows in the result:

```
$titles = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
  $titles[] = $row['name'];
}
```

Also, you really shouldn't be using mysql_* functions. Use mysqli or PDO. Here is the equivalent code using MySQLi:

```
//assuming you already have a mysqli connection
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT name FROM newsletters');
$titles = array();
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $titles[] = $row['name'];
}
```

If you need to add parameters to your queries that aren't hard coded you should read about prepared statements, especially if you're handling user input.

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't your read answer correctly at first and had to work it out but I see that you included the query at the top so that was my fault. It works fine. I'm finding PHP arrays a little tricky. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I simply add another example in addition to the already correct answer of mtinsley. An implementation with PDO:

```
$dbh = new PDO(/*dns*/);
$ids = array(1, 2, 3);
$place_holders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name FROM newsletters WHERE ID IN($place_holders)");
$sth->execute($ids);

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  // $title[] = $row['name']; ... or whatever you need to do
}
```